# How to freeze text from td that has roswpan when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, scroll

I'd like to freeze the `Content A` text that I applied `rowspan` on the table.
When scrolling down, it fixed at first, but as I go down to the middle point the text goes up and it disappears. So how do I freeze the text on the same spot until I scroll down to the very end?

```css
.scroll-container {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.sticky-cell {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 40%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sticky-text {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  z-index: 1;
}

span {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-container">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="sticky-cell" rowspan="12"><span>Content A</span></td>
        <td>Content B</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content D</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content F</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content E</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content G</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content I</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content J</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content K</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content L</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `sticky-cell` class to the `<tr>` parent element of "Content A".

Then set the `top` property of `sticky-cell` to zero.

```css
.sticky-cell {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 40%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  top: 0; /* set this */
}

.scroll-container {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.sticky-text {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  z-index: 1;
}

span {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-container">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="sticky-cell">
        <td rowspan="12"><span>Content A</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content B</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content D</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content F</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content E</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content G</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content I</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content J</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content K</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content L</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I also noticed that "Content B" and "Content A" were sharing the same `<tr>` parent so I fixed it by separating them.